# Find probability in r of the predicted values over a given threshold for the following months

Tags: r, probability, exceed

Hello to the community,

I have a two-year data on hourly basis. Is there any way to find the probability that the predicted values for each of the following months will exceed a given threshold which is the 80% of the maximum value of the last year? Thanks in advance.

```
threshold <- c(3021)

my_data <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,121,206,206,206,194,182,194,230,194,182,194,206,194,206,206,170,206,206,194,206,182,194,206,206,168,205,193,205,205,168,205,193,205,193,205,193,205,193,180,205,205,193,205,180,205,205,180,205,185,196,196,208,196,185,196,185,196,208,196,185,185,196,185,219,185,196,185,196,185,196,185,196,189,200,189,200,189,189,189,212,189,212,200,189,189,189,200,189,224,189,200,200,189,200,200,189,200,200,189,200,189,189,212,189,212,189,189,189,212,189,189,200,189,189,200,189,189,224,189,189,194,183,183,183,183,206,172,183,183,194,183,206,183,183,206,183,194,206,183,183,206,194,183,183,204,193,181,204,181,181,204,181,204,181,181,204,181,204,181,181,204,181,181,204,193,181,181,227,193,182,204,182,216,182,182,204,182,204,182,182,216,182,182,204,182,193,204,182,182,193,204,182,216,182,216,182,182,205,182,205,182,182,205,182,182,205,194,182,205,182,194,205,182,182,216,182,205,194,182,205,182,182,205,182,205,182,205,182,194,205,182,182,205,182,205,182,194,205,182,205,182,193,182,205,182,205,193,205,182,182,205,193,182,205,182,216,182,182,216,182,182,216,182,182,217,183,183,217,183,205,183,205,194,183,205,183,217,183,183,205,194,183,205,194,183,217,183,183,217,183,194,1177,1108,503,686,651,571,571,537,526,514,514,503,491,491,491,491,491,491,503,514,491,842,797,854,444,364,467,865,751,911,694,250,228,216,228,228,216,228,239,216,228,239,216,228,842,1459,1619,1539,1448,1470,1242,1140,1277,695,593,775,650,616,832,410,764,661,832,741,752,786,729,786,786,1620,1472,1221,1620,1792,1415,1540,1232,1221,1232,1221,1210,1221,1221,1210,1221,1130,1118,1153,1221,1221,1221,1221,1655,2264,1988,2494,2574,1804,1161,2574,2057,3562,3528,3401,3700,3137,2091,2700,2103,1597,2011,2436,2953,2838,1253,276,563,659,284,762,1239,1330,1694,1625,2410,3365,3421,3762,3785,1284,1432,1932,1444,1887,1887,1409,1841,1864,523,261,318,289,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,36,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,47,213,213,213,213,213,202,213,225,202,202,213,202,237,202,213,213,213,213,213,213,213,213,213,190,215,215,215,215,215,203,191,203,203,191,203,179,191,215,179,215,191,203,191,191,215,191,191,834,1781,1195,920,896,992,789,490,227,239,227,215,227,239,239,215,239,239,215,239,215,251,215,239,1207,1556,1030,1413,1461,1389,1257,1233,239,180,216,180,216,180,216,192,192,216,192,192,227,192,192,192,227,192,192,204,192,204,192,216,180,204,192,204,192,204,192,216,192,216,192,192,204,216,192,204,192,216,204,192,192,216,180,216,180,204,192,204,180,216,192,204,192,216,192,192,216,192,192,216,934,1892,1844,1054,1617,1329,1509,1497,898,790,767,790,790,743,731,707,539,587,731,755,695,491,719,731,850,802,1090,1389,1353,1377,1461,1557,1330,1186,1090,791,1186,1198,1186,731,1174,1186,1198,707,1198,1198,1102,767,1461,1569,1844,2335,2562,2035,1353,1006,2012,1988,3293,3245,3065,2203,2934,3173,503,910,1557,1305,3137,3532,2993,3676,2598,1167,460,672,731,2995,3184,3561,2995,2842,2653,884,1415,1415,1557,3396,3809,3325,3844,2394,1167,1203,2016,1132,1215,1851,1792,896,1816,1203,236,200,212,271,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,46,205,183,205,171,183,194,205,194,171,194,183,194,183,194,183,205,183,183,205,183,205,171,183,183,183,183,171,183,194,183,171,183,194,183,171,183,171,183,183,183,183,183,171,183,183,183,183,183,183,183,183,172,206,172,172,183,172,172,183,195,183,183,183,183,183,183,183,195,183,160,183,195,183,183,172,183,172,206,172,172,172,183,195,172,183,183,183,183,183,183,183,183,183,1099,1660,1534,985,847,847,939,870,218,183,172,183,172,206,183,172,183,183,183,172,183,183,183,183,950,1489,1191,1168,779,756,870,836,240,183,172,172,183,195,183,172,183,172,183,183,183,172,183,183,1248,1489,1031,974,962,710,859,928,618,515,882,1363,1088,893,424,321,515,515,515,275,458,515,504,309,1649,1901,1810,1822,1845,1650,1123,1192,1833,1948,1283,1867,1971,2108,2899,2624,2841,2841,2624,2452,3998,3483,3483,3334,1810,1054,985,515,1443,3310,3803,3058,3184,2142,928,2085,1592,1409,1695,3791,3459,3723,3230,2119,939,1100,1203,1787,859,1867,1787,767,160,103,160,286,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,69,723,2366,1562,1165,1107,1130,1398,571,198,210,175,210,175,210,186,175,210,186,186,210,186,186,210,851,1259,1188,1095,1037,979,932,850,676,210,175,210,198,186,175,210,186,210,186,186,210,186,186,186,210,186,186,209,186,175,209,175,198,198,186,198,198,175,198,186,198,186,209,175,209,186,186,209,1781,1827,1792,1382,1405,1522,1440,1253,1323,1487,1452,1265,1312,1476,1276,1066,1323,1218,1300,1440,1101,1241,1218,1218,1382,2377,2586,2380,2345,1575,1012,1713,3345,3380,3759,3713,1747,862,2046,1621,1989,2449,3460,3908,2449,1586,1678,977,1035,2989,2594,2927,2640,2077,1492,1136,1239,1262,1308,1722,1297,172,287,402,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,114,160,172,160,172,172,149,172,172,172,149,172,172,149,172,172,149,183,149,172,160,183,149,160,951,1397,1134,1077,802,1237,710,985,218,172,149,172,172,149,172,149,172,183,149,172,160,172,160,172,160,172,160,172,149,172,172,149,172,172,172,172,149,172,149,172,183,149,172,160,172,160,183,149,183,160,149,183,149,172,172,149,172,149,172,172,172,149,172,149,172,172,160,172,160,172,160,172,1260,1421,1248,1397,1306,1042,1546,1008,1466,1099,1180,1214,951,1294,779,1363,893,1306,985,1214,1054,1054,962,1260,1901,2119,2084,2370,2095,2347,1855,1523,2782,3171,3206,2610,1591,1672,1408,2427,3126,2496,2622,1901,1912,1706,1855,3148,2164,2278,2403,1865,1121,1144,893,1327,2861,2643,2151,3891,3204,3181,1064,1156,355,1636,2838,3845,2208,2128,1774,1385,1121,2861,3834,2174,2254,1224,1110,1350,2586,2975,3593,2094,1865,1739,1396,1865,3158,3731,3090,2117,1545,1293,1545,744,2495,3685,3720,1477,904,1557,504,996,1156,1728,881,1385,538,172,343,332,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,92,160,183,160,172,149,160,172,172,160,172,172,149,172,160,172,160,172,160,160,183,160,160,160,183,149,160,183,149,172,160,172,149,172,172,149,160,149,183,149,172,149,206,172,183,149,183,149,160,183,149,149,183,149,172,172,149,172,149,172,149,172,160,149,160,149,160,149,160,160,160,126,1123,1479,1215,1444,1169,1158,1135,699,688,1100,413,940,699,413,905,332,883,550,504,905,401,756,550,378,1158,1295,859,1570,917,1054,1364,848,791,562,424,413,413,252,894,882,894,768,802,882,905,768,779,1077,1902,2510,2315,2717,1994,1754,2315,2017,1674,2820,3209,3565,3060,2166,1880,1375,745,3588,3347,3599,2132,1204,1524,745,1696,2740,3070,3678,1043,951,687,561,836,1169,2051,2921,2738,2475,1650,1249,1432,1707,1249,1226,1512,1822,1008,195,115,504,664,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,620,2157,1733,1326,1651,1012,1244,1267,616,802,407,384,395,384,372,395,384,372,233,314,372,384,360,186,1163,1077,561,722,710,298,767,687,951,1168,619,1214,859,1157,802,1042,1065,962,962,905,1157,813,1054,893,1443,1850,1313,1496,1347,1599,1599,1302,1953,2375,2878,3049,2329,3129,1987,2158,1987,1325,2512,1233,1039,183,411,183,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,91,160,149,149,160,1532,1235,755,1292,617,1063,595,846,537,640,698,709,698,686,629,480,617,778,492,1086,962,1557,1111,1191,1191,1752,1614,1557,1339,1580,1603,1454,1500,1271,1832,1362,1637,1225,1729,1477,1225,1672,1339,1534,938,1511,996,790,1213,881,1190,755,1224,1110,1819,2106,1591,1156,2415,1831,2483,2907,2735,3227,2289,2506,2186,801,1578,1556,2139,2105,3294,2150,1121,1064,1315,1235,2905,3283,3145,2722,1144,709,1556,1109,2265,3489,3145,1578,1395,961,1430,2151,3340,3523,2071,789,995,1602,1087,1418,1007,1750,561,172,435,217,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,46,148,160,148,160,148,148,171,148,160,148,171,148,148,148,148,160,148,160,148,160,148,160,160,148,1016,514,1427,925,982,925,993,217,194,171,183,194,171,194,171,194,171,194,183,194,171,205,171,708,1062,948,971,937,960,914,765,777,960,925,925,651,765,857,834,857,845,845,845,868,845,765,697,880,845,811,845,674,1051,1691,1714,1245,1565,1325,1497,2079,2182,1714,2411,1657,2193,2468,3245,2879,3199,2708,2662,2091,800,1976,1748,1165,1954,1656,1622,823,811,1805,3096,3313,3210,2102,1805,960,1005,3781,3073,3576,2822,1554,1268,971,1178,1498,1292,1635,366,183,252,183,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,103,148,160,171,148,160,160,171,171,148,171,160,160,171,171,148,171,148,1118,2225,1997,1392,1906,1210,1290,1278,696,902,593,822,856,422,833,445,719,605,582,708,445,776,377,799,559,1414,1015,1426,992,1403,924,1357,1118,1471,1380,2441,2509,2760,2281,2179,2281,1403,1563,2384,2498,2954,3582,2030,787,1289,1334,821,297,2304,2772,3296,2133,2452,1802,1483,844,673,1506,1905,2429,3593,3273,1722,798,1084,502,1585,2600,2101,2307,3472,1998,594,1405,777,982,228,1793,2695,2866,1656,2866,1393,1210,1119,343,856,1759,1747,537,1565,1450,137,149,229,377,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1119,1504,1313,742,1142,582,1381,936,1404,1062,1279,1027,982,1244,1244,1050,1176,1256,1062,1187,890,970,1267,1256,1313,982,1289,1346,844,913,1312,730,1734,1152,1426,1073,1335,1118,1267,1004,924,924,913,924,936,936,936,936,1107,1906,2163,2095,1810,1879,2027,1628,2198,3553,3325,2710,2095,3029,1549,1981,1924,2175,1116,1583,751,148,592,68,228,0,216,239,148,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,80,183,148,148,160,148,183,148,148,171,148,160,148,171,160,148,148,160,148,183,148,148,160,148,160,148,183,148,160,148,148,171,148,160,171,148,148,171,148,148,160,148,171,160,148,160,148,183,11,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1803,1791,1642,1263,1286,1240,1194,528,161,149,161,149,138,172,149,149,161,161,149,172,149,149,149,172,1563,1586,1597,1232,1746,1495,1597,913,799,742,685,799,810,810,821,821,616,821,821,833,616,821,856,1871,3127,2956,2317,3070,1187,1404,2591,3173,2956,2465,2032,1495,1666,2888,3401,1746,2979,1575,1141,2717,2328,1883,993,1119,2089,2934,1884,1804,2261,2272,948,1667,2169,2009,2934,2843,2283,2877,2238,1404,2500,2694,1930,2660,1884,1279,1302,925,1396,1808,2128,1979,2551,2586,1602,904,1064,1258,2025,2711,1350,1396,1430,995,217,172,366,23,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,68,97,28,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,774,1320,945,888,489,853,546,774,148,125,148,148,148,125,148,148,125,148,159,125,148,137,148,137,1081,1423,763,1081,535,1753,1115,1252,262,148,148,148,148,171,148,148,148,125,159,148,159,148,148,159,1593,1847,1163,1562,1026,1163,1801,1106,1562,1117,1379,1243,1186,1288,878,1448,923,1493,946,1471,969,1140,1117,1334,1562,1632,2477,2922,2945,2408,2922,1267,3071,2511,3093,2306,3013,2397,1119,1004,1233,1655,2876,2511,2682,2477,2374,1587,3013,617,480,2078,1188,2706,2775,2501,1941,879,1382,1279,971,2957,3072,3631,2889,2021,1816,856,2352,2592,3768,2112,1325,902,1347,1553,2615,1781,1644,719,148,126,331,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,46,125,103,103,103,125,103,114,103,103,114,103,114,103,114,103,114,570,1574,1140,1426,1106,1266,1015,1209,1026,1163,718,376,411,445,445,445,433,388,365,388,388,456,433,445,365,354,536,2076,1928,1905,1871,1700,1403,1791,1232,1734,1095,1540,993,1426,1107,1323,1164,1209,1312,1095,1278,1529,2601,2554,2360,2006,2132,1927,2223,1847,2326,2645,2896,1562,1756,1562,1493,1619,2918,3488,2896,1938,1824,1721,798,2941,2941,2586,2620,968,638,1424,1401,1082,2848,3099,1185,1857,1652,1595,684,775,1276,2449,3224,3258,3201,1686,1322,934,171,694,876,888,1184,1730,797,125,102,353,125,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,296,740,683,671,660,660,615,615,592,569,398,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,68,114,114,114,102,114,102,114,102,114,102,102,114,102,114,102,114,102,114,114,114,102,114,114,114,114,102,114,114,102,102,102,114,102,102,114,102,102,114,125,114,114,102,114,91,102,114,114,956,2073,1424,1561,1265,1003,1230,786,114,103,103,114,103,114,103,114,103,137,80,114,114,125,114,91,934,1825,1163,1334,365,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,68,102,91,114,114,125,114,102,114,114,102,137,125,114,114,102,114,114,102,114,137,102,114,114,1344,1868,1891,1230,1424,1390,1469,1036,1367,1447,877,1207,478,444,569,319,581,364,513,433,467,467,410,490,399,478,398,91,114,80,922,637,592,239,398,0,80,1229,1093,785,1115,979,854,1093,763,1047,990,1024,2606,1867,2015,1913,1514,1731,1765,1400,1651,1731,1264,1583,2049,1708,1992,1890,2095,1480,2436,2596,3176,1947,2436,2698,911,753,2567,1677,2304,2441,2202,2053,1529,1186,1723,2498,2704,1837,2407,2670,2111,1791,1985,2875,1711,2099,2293,2202,993,1689,2659,1324,2134,2088,1837,2351,2054,2841,1654,1677,1803,479,1369,2955,3275,2499,2099,1963,2054,1381,3081,3685,2533,1358,787,1529,1221,1324,2111,2841,3104,2818,1175,947,1518,593,2544,3320,3400,1894,2008,1951,228,2191,2624,3663,2271,1197,1220,536,604,947,969,1699,1061,114,148,525,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,885,601,556,284,1226,409,1055,397,522,340,465,522,522,760,931,862,670,931,828,715,896,760,772,1384,1555,1101,1339,1124,1714,1147,1385,919,942,931,942,885,874,863,942,942,942,965,942,942,954,942,908,1714,2679,1952,2350,1362,1691,3133,2770,3269,1589,2758,2259,2304,2611,2940,2202,1464,2906,2236,965,1578,2724,2781,2633,1407,2349,2292,692,2043,1600,1940,942,2905,3075,2860,1952,1770,1055,374,2984,3302,3291,1475,1316,1112,885,2088,3393,3461,2022,943,659,329,1306,3090,3488,2056,2181,1136,1363,886,545,1170,1409,1761,420,159,375,80,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,249,760,748,703,737,1724,1678,1486,1134,1202,862,839,839,862,828,851,851,839,703,760,885,851,851,726,2098,2111,1850,1635,1771,1567,1850,1271,1657,1112,1612,1260,2236,2066,2168,1794,2077,2077,1567,1317,3190,3303,2554,2009,2293,1408,942,1340,954,1555,2078,1067,2623,2430,3440,2895,1203,897,2089,500,1873,3133,3860,2078,2089,1192,1124,1896,2407,2929,3667,2815,2248,1328,454,375,1022,1249,2214,3701,3065,1396,1260,1226,965,1419,1578,806,159,250,261,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,68,930,738,443,499,579,851,1362,1112,386,1033,374,749,567,408,919,374,579,533,352,715,533,352,647,1100,1486,1146,1248,1679,1270,1962,1622,1282,1622,1055,1690,1146,1361,1452,1066,1769,1077,1304,1508,1089,1622,1202,1066,1315,839,1088,1202,839,1338,1462,1372,1576,1632,1632,2573,2777,1712,1700,2857,3797,2834,3049,2913,2097,1916,2210,3866,3469,2132,2188,726,1474,1020,3243,2812,2835,1361,2494,3299,2324,1973,2098,2245,1667,1542,1100,159,181,295,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,45,113,113,91,91,113,113,91,102,113,91,113,102,91,113,91,113,91,113,91,113,91,113,91,498,1586,1812,1450,1427,2141,1790,1314,2130,2198,1495,1858,2254,1405,1699,2175,1518,1631,1835,1223,1676,1858,1087,1439,1790,1348,1461,1620,1065,1337,1711,1020,1224,1473,1201,1518,2606,2617,2617,2436,2288,2991,2730,2764,1858,2685,2798,2017,2230,2095,1415,1189,1540,2751,2966,2887,3000,2004,1223,1325,1642,2740,3261,3272,2004,1562,1302,509,3566,3317,3714,1279,804,770,1506,645,1619,1607,1438,1268,283,158,283,419,57,91,68,91,68,68,91,68,91,68,91,68,68,91,79,91,57,68,91,68,45,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,45,125,113,136,113,125,113,113,136,113,113,136,113,136,113,113,136,113,113,113,136,113,125,113,136,102,136,102,136,113,125,113,136,113,113,125,113,136,113,113,136,102,136,113,136,102,113,136,113,125,113,136,113,102,136,113,136,113,113,125,113,113,136,113,113,136,102,136,113,113,136,113,125,113,136,113,113,125,113,113,136,113,136,102,113,136,113,113,136,113,113,113,136,113,113,136,113,125,113,136,113,113,125,113,113,136,113,113,136,113,113,136,113,113,136,113,102,136,113,113,136,113,102,136,113,113,125,113,136,113,113,136,113,102,136,113,113,113,136,113,113,136,113,113,136,113,113,125,113,113,136,113,113,136,113,113,136,113,113,113,136,113,113,136,113,113,125,113,181,181,181,181,159,181,181,181,159,181,181,159,181,181,159,193,181,1429,1678,1100,1123,1383,1145,1372,1599,1293,1304,941,1202,1202,930,1259,873,1236,1089,794,1236,1111,930,1213,1270,2041,1463,1327,1747,1338,1293,1429,1043,1452,1248,1350,1531,1202,2007,1690,1883,2075,1781,1996,1259,2824,3607,3425,2370,2699,1236,1281,1157,1610,2744,3674,2733,2869,1984,1191,1690,2812,2914,3152,1724,2619,1055,1066,1950,1746,2132,2699,2393,2348,2348,1769,851,1384,1361,2563,1497,2813,1883,1542,2155,2064,1111,2699,1985,1758,1520,181,204,408,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,68,137,114,148,114,137,114,159,114,137,114,125,114,137,114,160,114,114,137,114,125,137,137,171,137,137,114,137,103,137,137,137,114,137,114,137,114,137,114,114,137,114,137,114,137,160,183,171,206,160,183,160,160,183,160,171,183,160,160,171,183,160,1418,1963,1498,1010,1951,1463,1532,1917,1679,1747,1373,1770,1543,1645,1316,1566,1452,1475,1520,1475,1475,1475,1475,1554,1985,2041,2132,1883,2075,1712,2132,3958,3731,2880,2302,2744,1588,1814,2098,2540,2495,1894,3277,3153,1134,862,1996,907,1633,1168,318,2370,2109,1452,726,658,794,1928,1259,1803,1780,601,147,442,136,113,113,147,136,136,125,136,136,102,113,113,136,102,113,113,102,113,125,113,136,125,113,113,136,102,159,136,125,113,136,125,136,113,113,102,136,113,125,113,113,102,113,136,102,113,113,113,113,113,113,136,113,113,113,113,113,136,113,113,113,113,113,113,136,102,113,113,113,113,136,113,113,113,136,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,125,113,113,113,113,136,113,113,113,113,113,113,136,113,113,125,113,113,113,113,465,1293,1508,839,1576,975,1440,987,1134,1191,646,1463,873,1270,839,862,1179,1179,975,1179,1191,975,1179,1440,1599,1350,1735,1758,2019,1588,1622,1735,2008,1996,2155,2518,2042,2439,3006,3800,3153,2473,2938,2609,1781,1395,2268,3811,2931,2577,2418,2771,1882,1733,2326,3147,2999,1847,2144,1813,1015,2087,2064,2406,1733,1585,536,205,365,171,114,137,114,114,114,114,114,137,114,114,114,126,114,114,137,103,114,114,137,114,114,114,126,114,114,114,137,114,114,103,137,114,114,137,103,114,114,137,114,114,137,114,114,114,114,137,126,114,114,114,126,114,114,137,126,114,114,114,126,114,114,137,114,114,114,137,114,114,114,114,114,137,126,114,114,114,114,114,126,137,103,114,137,114,114,126,114,114,114,137,114,114,114,114,137,114,114,114,114,137,137,114,137,137,137,137,160,126,137,149,137,137,137,137,137,137,137,126,137,137,137,137,1568,1110,1293,939,1339,1454,1156,1282,1419,1488,1099,1442,1362,1213,1500,1168,1351,1351,1099,1042,1019,1042,1042,1179,1492,866,968,1230,991,1287,1025,1105,1265,854,1265,1766,1595,2165,1800,1982,1846,2301,1914,3065,3418,3714,2609,2096,2313,2166,1973,1928,3084,2687,1780,2064,1939,2177,1327,1542,2824,3459,3141,2370,2835,1145,1111,1712,2472,2710,1848,2755,2178,1815,2212,964,1236,1497,2144,1146,2767,2688,2892,1520,1440,1826,1928,1554,1384,1803,692,181,386,170,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,34,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,91,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,113,91,113,113,113,113,113,125,113,91,113,113,113,114,137,148,160,137,160,137,160,46,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,45,739,875,1057,477,1160,864,409,1330,1239,910,1251,978,1171,887,1228,1000,932,1205,887,773,932,728,830,1931,1158,1624,1772,1363,1556,1738,1329,1510,1170,1124,1351,931,1204,1306,1136,1227,977,1351,1113,977,988,909,954,1358,1277,1312,1521,975,1381,987,1346,1172,1335,1300,1312,1996,1312,1625,1730,1474,2008,1300,1950,3517,2948,2263,2496,1849,1093,1237,1969,1921,2881,3746,2881,3386,2173,852,1945,1141,2857,3098,1873,2653,1513,1405,2221,1921,2113,2677,2209,3483,3218,1141,2642,1417,1753,1501,2366,2546,2762,4011,2558,1873,2017,1657,973,1537,1813,1045,216,216,492,120,144,120,120,144,132,120,144,120,144,108,120,144,120,120,144,120,132,144,120,120,144,120,120,120,144,120,132,144,120,120,144,120,120,144,132,120,144,120,120,144,120,132,144,120,120,156,120,120,144,130,142,130,118,142,118,142,130,142,118,142,118,118,142,118,142,118,142,130,118,142,118,142,118,136,125,136,113,136,113,136,136,125,113,136,113,136,136,113,136,113,136,136,113,136,113,136,136,113,136,113,158,113,136,124,158,136,124,113,136,136,102,136,113,136,124,113,136,136,102,158,136,113,136,113,136,136,113,136,113,136,136,113,136,136,113,136,113,136,147,113,136,113,147,113,136,125,136,749,1090,625,1397,852,1249,1181,1067,1181,920,1306,852,806,693,863,852,863,852,659,829,863,1147,1890,1101,1437,1009,1322,1078,1217,1159,951,1287,893,869,869,811,835,858,869,869,881,869,869,869,869,869,879,706,798,879,856,844,856,844,648,856,856,868,856,682,821,937,879,706,960,937,798,821,949,914,2002,1584,1674,1618,1358,1742,2138,2806,1301,1742,1211,1720,3168,3564,2353,3168,3417,2297,1131,1686,2670,3383,1550,2002,1107,2068,1887,1243,1661,1932,2384,2215,2576,1367,2158,1424,2260,1977,2249,2339,1684,1175,226,294,418,158,181,158,192,158,158,158,192,158,158,192,158,181,158,169,158,181,169,158,192,158,158,192,158,158,169,181,170,158,158,192,158,136,136,147,136,136,136,136,136,136,147,136,113,136,147,136,147,113,136,147,136,147,113,136,136,147,136,158,181,181,181,181,181,181,170,181,181,192,158,192,192,181,170,181,1458,1628,1029,1436,746,1424,961,1390,791,1040,1176,916,1130,961,757,961,825,893,859,870,848,882,803,904,713,1584,1618,939,1234,679,883,917,928,781,792,928,928,656,939,939,894,702,928,939,668,939,928,690,1494,2400,1528,2637,1686,2388,1800,2954,2694,3509)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see the guidelines on how to post a question with a minimal, reproducible example -- https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example -- and then take another crack at this.

Comment: Please share a little bit of sample data. About 10-20 rows sampled from 3 consecutive months is plenty to illustrate the problem. Using `dput()` is the nicest way to share data because it's copy/pasteable, for example `dput(droplevels(your_data[c(1:10, 51:60)]))` to share rows 1 to 10 and 51 to 60. [See this FAQ for more advice on making reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

If `values` is a vector storing all of your values, `mean(values > 0.8(max(values)))` would give you the sample proportion above the sample maximum.

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your instant response but is not that simple what I want to find is    1-Probability(predicted values for next m<= 0.8×max( actual value of y-1)). In other words I want to predict the proportion of extreme values of my sample above that threshold.